# Separar por día, mes, y año, un campo de un dataset, requiero realizar búsquedas por mes o fin de semana

Tags: python, machine-learning

Cargo el dataset por medio de un archivo cvs, lo estoy realizando en Python

```
nombre_archivo = 'ParkingComedie.csv'
df = pd.read_csv (nombre_archivo )
df.head(10)
Datetime     Nom du parking   #disponibles   #TotalPlazas
25/10/2021   Comédie           320            400
24/01/2019   Comédie           120            400
21/11/2020   Centro            250            500
```

Lo que hice inicialmente es cambiar el formato del campo Datetime ya que estaba en tipo objeto

```
 df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'],errors='coerce')`
```

Aquí estoy intentando realizar una regresión lineal simple:

```
Y = df["Nombre de places disponibles"]
X = pd.DataFrame({'Intercept':np.ones(len(df)), 
'Nombredeplacesdisponibles': Y,'DateTime': 
df["DateTime"],'Nombredeplacestotales': df["Nombre de places 
totales"],'Pourcentagedeplacesdisponibles': df["Pourcentage de 
places disponibles"] })

reg = smf.ols('Nombredeplacesdisponibles ~ DateTime + 
Nombredeplacestotales + Pourcentagedeplacesdisponibles', data = X)
```

Por último:

```
res = reg.fit()
print(res.summary())
```

Sin embargo mi resultado de R-squard es, por ese motivo deseo partir la fecha para poder realizar búsquedas francinadas para que el R-squard disminuya un poco.

Comment: Buen día, por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega algunas filas de tu `dataset` como texto, no como imagen. También agrega el código de lo que has intentado hacer ya que parte importante de la cultura del sitio es que los usuarios muestren un esfuerzo por resolver sus propias preguntas, sin mostrar lo que se ha intentado hacer lo más probable es que la pregunta termine cerrada. Saludos!

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, ya la edite mil Gracias

Comment: Buen día, veo que has editado tu pregunta y agregado más información, pero la aún no has puesto lo que has intentado para "separar" por día, mes y año.

Comment: También ¿Podrías agregar un ejemplo de como debería ser el `dataset` después de separar por día, mes y/o año? Ya que no es muy claro que datos o columnas se deben obtener al final. ¿O bastaría con agregar columnas con día, mes y año por separado?

Comment: O bastaría con agregar columnas con día, mes y año por separado?  Si es eso

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Para todas las columnas que son del tipo `datetime64[ns]` se puede acceder al día, mes y año a través de [`pandas.Series.dt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html)

Utilizando las líneas que pusiste en un `dataframe` de prueba (En el archivo "sample2.csv"):

```
    Datetime    Nom du parking  #disponibles    #TotalPlazas
0   2021-10-25  Comédie         320             400
1   2019-01-24  Comédie         120             400
2   2020-11-21  Centro          250             500
```

Creamos las columnas para día, mes y año:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample2.csv')
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'], errors = 'coerce', infer_datetime_format = True)
df['Día'] = df['Datetime'].dt.day
df['Mes'] = df['Datetime'].dt.month
df['Año'] = df['Datetime'].dt.year
```

De esta forma obtenemos el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
    Datetime    Nom du parking  #disponibles    #TotalPlazas    Día Mes Año
0   2021-10-25  Comédie         320             400             25  10  2021
1   2019-01-24  Comédie         120             400             24  1   2019
2   2020-11-21  Centro          250             500             21  11  2020
```

Comment: OHHHHH, Millll Mill gracias, has sido de gran ayuda

Comment: @AnamaUrrea, si la respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. Lectura recomendada [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).